# How to enable curl in xampp?

Tags: php, curl, xampp

How to enable curl in xampp ?

My PHP twitter application needs curl function. But it is not enabled in XAMPP. how to enable it. I found no options for doing that.

Comment: A very basic tutorial on curl -> http://www.technofusions.com/curl-in-php-tutorial-basics/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have to modify the php.ini files in your xampp folder. Three files in three different places need to be changed.

Follow the following steps to enable curl library with XAMPP in Windows:

### Step 1:

Browse and open the following 3 files

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

### Step 2:

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file by removing the semicolon (;).

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After that it will look something like something below-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

### Step 3:

Restart your Apache server.

### Step 4:

Check your `phpinfo()` to see whether curl has properly enabled or not.

Enjoy using curl() library.

Comment: Worked great!  The current version of Xampp only uses a single php.ini (phew!) which is in ./php/php.ini so I only needed to make the update in one spot.

Comment: **+1**, Beautifully put-up.

Comment: Post is old now, XAMPP Version: 5.6.30 has only one \xampp\php\php.ini file, apache\bin or php\php4\ is not available

Comment: in latest versions it is like extension=curl and it is already enabled. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir yet the error still occurs

Answer (score 50):

It should be available in php.ini file. You need to un-comment the line for curl extension:

```
  ;extension=php_curl.dll
  ^----- remove semi-colon
```

Comment: where to find that file ? in which folder

Comment: e.g. c:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: cannot find extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini filr

Answer (score 23):

In XAMPP installation directory, open `%XAMPP_HOME%/php/php.ini` file. Uncomment the following line:
`extension=php_curl.dll`

PS: If that doesn't work then check whether `%XAMPP_HOME%/php/ext/php_curl.dll` file exist or not.

Answer (score 5):

1) C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini

2) Uncomment the following line on your php.ini file by removing the semicolon.

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

3) Restart your apache server.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have `libcurl` (see: http://curl.haxx.se) installed. Then make sure your copy of PHP has been compiled with the `--with-curl[=DIR]` flag. For more info see:

- http://au.php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php
- http://au.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

If XAMPP comes pre-compiled with cURL you may just need to enable the extension in your php.ini file (usually by removing a semicolon at the start of the line which includes the extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can add any extension (in Wamp and Xampp servers) by removing the semi-colon (;)

Comment: Unless you specify where to remove the semi-colon, this is hardly helpful to most of users. I'm marking this "Recommended Deletion" from the review panel but once you update your answer other reviewers probably won't do that. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP on MACOS or Linux, remove the semicolon in php.ini file after **extension=curl.so**

Comment: Not sure about linux, but `extension=curl.so` is not in the php.ini file for XAMPP on Mac OS X.

Comment: I can't find php.ini

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini ?