# Enabling the cURL library for PHP using XAMPP for Windows

Tags: php, curl, error-handling, xampp

I am running PHP code with the following code invovled:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

When I get to this line, the following error is returned:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\API\IPVIKING_API.php on line 79

Now I've found all the answers talking about enabling the curl extension in the php.ini file, and I've done that, following this question here: [How to enable curl in xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp).

My problem is I do not have these 3 files:

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

I instead have 2 files called

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini-development
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini-production
```

I've uncommented the

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

line in both of them, restarted both my browser and xampp, yet it still gives me the same error. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

there you can see which **php.ini** is loaded. In this file you uncomment the the extension line.

When there is no php.ini in this path which is in the phpinfo this should be **xampp/php/php.ini** then rename one of the two files

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini-development
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just did what you said, I restarted xampp and the browser, yet it still gives me the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you look in your phpinfo wheather the curl extension is loaded?

Comment: I'm unsure where exactly to look for this. On the xamp phpinfo() page, it has C:\xampp\php\php.ini as the loaded configuration file (which I commented out), and it has API20090626,TS,VC9 as the php extension builds. If its not one of these places, please let me know where I should be looking?

Comment: There is a complete section for curl. You can search for "cURL support" this should have the value "enabled" and you can look to your error log. (C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log) perhaps there are some more informations.

Comment: I do not seem to have this section. I tried a search for just "curl" which gave no responses and then also "support", sifting through the support responses still nothing.

Comment: Then the curl module is not loaded. Then check the apache error logs. Perhaps you have a wrong version or something else. I have tried it here on my computer and its working well. And you could check wheather the php_curl.dll is in the php module folder.

Comment: got it! It required a complete system shut down.  Thanks for sticking with me until I got it!

Comment: I had to add the following to my PHP code to get things to work: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should move C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini-production to C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini.

```
rename "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini-production" "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini"
```

And then change:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Then restart Apache.

Some systems require two files to be copied from where PHP is installed to your WINDOWS\System32 directory:

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

**Update:**

```
copy "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini" "C:\xampp\php\php.ini"
```

Comment: I have changed it. It's still giving the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you restarted apache/xampp?

Comment: I've physically shut down xampp, and then restarted it. I figured apache would be included in that process. Is that untrue?

Comment: Depending on your OS, I have seen issues where restarting XAMPP does not restart the Apache service if you opted to install as a server. Go to Start, Run, type in `services.msc` look for apache and choose restart.

Comment: Also, look at the updated answer. Run the last command, `copy "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini" "C:\xampp\php\php.ini"` then restart apache, try again.

Answer (score 1):

search for 'php.ini' file in

> xampp\php\ directory

open php.ini

find for 'curl'

you will get line

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

uncomment it by removing semicolon at front of the line

> extension=php_curl.dll

Answer (score 0):

There is a file named php (I think this is the real php.ini) with the type as configuration settings that is the one you need to uncomment extension = php_curl.dll. You should also uncomment the `.ini-development` and `.ini-production`. Restart and both browser and apache and it should work.