# cURL post request script giving "undefined function curl_init"

Tags: php, post, curl

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol.php on line 9

Basically this isn't working, I have no idea what's wrong with it all of the fields in the POST request are correct (As a HTML post form with a action to the URL works perfectly).

Script:

```
<?php
$url = 'myurl';
$postData = array();
$postData['name'] = 'jay'
$postData['age'] = '0';
$postData['gender'] ='female';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Add `echo curl_error($ch);` after `$result = curl_exec($ch);` -- does it output anything?

Comment: Nothing happens, even if i put a echo after it. It doesn't do what I want, since nothing pops up in my database (should appear in my database don't worry about that part though)

Comment: the first thing would be to identify if the request is sent. If yes, is this received ? If yes, the the erro is most probably in the script  at 'myurl'... And yes we should worry on that part as you don't provide any info on what isn't working exactly

Answer (score 1):

Your code is showing syntax error, in `$postData['name'] = 'jay'`

```
 $postData = array();
 $postData['name'] = 'jay';
 $postData['age'] = '0';
 $postData['gender'] ='female';
```

To make sure you have enabled curl or not. just place this inyour php file and find curl extension enabled in your instance.

```
 <?php phpinfo();?>
```

Enable curl in windows xampp: [How to enable curl in xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this. Just goes to show how important an IDE with a built in parser can be.

Comment: @user3000453: Yeah, that's very descriptive.

Comment: @user3000453: Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script. See if that changes anything?

Comment: What is your curl call url ? `$url = 'myurl';`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol.php on line 9

Comment: You need to enable or install curl in your machine.

Comment: Done that, blank page like on other host.

Comment: Did you restarted your server i.e apache and check curel extension loaded or not ?

Comment: Did you checked curl get loaded or not  using phpinfo(); function

Comment: End of the code you add this line print_r($result);  echo "test";  and update me