# Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension error

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am creating a Facebook app using php...downloaded the php-sdk from github but everytime I  run the file I get this error ---

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.

I have removed the comment from php.ini file stored in xampp/php but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Ensure you installed curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows

Answer (score 6):

If you Operating System is `Ubuntu`

To solve this exception ,you need to download `curl` for `php5` .

1) Just run this command line from your terminal  :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

2) Then restart your `apache` :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your changes,

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

CURL support enabled is necessary.

[Enabling CURL in PHP (PHP.ini, WAMP, XAMPP, Ubuntu)](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/).

Following steps to enable curl library with XAMPP in Windows:

### Step 1:

Browse and open the following 3 files

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

### Step 2:

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file by removing the semicolon (;).

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After that it will look something like something below-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

### Step 3:

Restart your Apache server.

### Step 4:

Check your `phpinfo()` to see whether curl has properly enabled or not.

Comment: I don't have these files---
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini

Comment: @user3168567, you find any of the php.ini file & edit it with other steps

Comment: @user3168567 which version u have in php?

Comment: I have PHP Version 5.3.5 ....
and i have edited the file C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: @user3168567 check phpini in php5.3.5 folder.C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php5.3.5\php.ini or C:\Program Files\xampp\php5.3.5\php.ini

Comment: @user3168567 If this answer is helpful to you, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the changes when you output

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Maybe you forgot to restart your apache server after you made the changes?

Comment: no i did restart the apache server but still getting the error

Comment: are the changes indeed reflected in the phpinfo() output.. otherwise you're probably are changing the wrong php.ini file.. the correct location is also in the phpinfo() output :)

Comment: some usefull hints here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp