# curl doesn't work on PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-url-shortener

I'm making an application, using Google URL Shortener API.

On MackBook Pro, the following code does work, but on Windows PC, it doesn't work and shows only "NULL" on the screen.

```
<?php 

// APIkey
$apiKey = '[Here is my API KEY]';

$longUrl = "http://www.absolute-keitarou.net/blog/";

$url1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key='.$apiKey;
$params = json_encode(array(
"longUrl" => $longUrl
));

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($res);
?>
```

On the MacBook, the code does work properly and shows the following.

object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["kind"]=> string(16) "urlshortener#url" ["id"]=> string(19) "http://goo.gl/TMII0" ["longUrl"]=> string(38) "http://www.absolute-keitarou.net/blog/" }

I want the Windows PC to shows the same output as the MacBook. Please tell me what I should do.

Comment: adding 'curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);' seems to help. Also, decode the result '$res' as  a separate step. This allows you to read the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open php.ini file at wamp/bin/php/php5.4/php.ini \

on XAMP there are three php.ini

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp)

search ;extension=php_curl.dll and remove semicolon

extension=php_curl.dll then save and and restart server

and change the port of server from 80 to 88 , 8088 ..etc etc, and how to change the port you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already removed it. My php.ini is in C:\xampp\php. I don't where wamp/bin/php/php5.4/php.ini is.

Comment: Ok now you can see xamp icon is green at your taskbar , right click on it restart the server and goto php extension see is php curl on or not or open phpinfo();

Comment: I don't know where xampp icon is and where my taskbar is. But phpinfo() shows
[[ curl

cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.24.0
Age 3]]

Has curl been available?

Comment: Now you need to change the port of Apache it will be 80 ,  you have to change it port http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port