# Dropbox api not working in codiegniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function request_dropbox()
{
    $params['key'] = 'gr3kempuvsiqsli';
    $params['secret'] = 'qtdl8lmm9r0rlk1';

    $this->load->library('dropbox', $params); 

    $data = $this->dropbox->get_request_token(base_url());
    $this->session->set_userdata('token_secret', $data['token_secret']);
    redirect($data['redirect']);
}
//This method should not be called directly, it will be called after 
//the user approves your application and dropbox redirects to it
public function access_dropbox()
{
    $params['key'] = 'gr3kempuvsiqsli';
    $params['secret'] = 'qtdl8lmm9r0rlk1';

    $this->load->library('dropbox', $params);
    $oauth = $this->dropbox->get_access_token($this->session->userdata('token_secret'));        
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token', $oauth['oauth_token']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token_secret', $oauth['oauth_token_secret']);
    redirect('welcome/test_dropbox');
}
//Once your application is approved you can proceed to load the library
//with the access token data stored in the session. If you see your account
//information printed out then you have successfully authenticated with
//dropbox and can use the library to interact with your account.
public function test_dropbox()
{
    $params['key'] = 'gr3kempuvsiqsli';
    $params['secret'] = 'qtdl8lmm9r0rlk1';
    $params['access'] = array('oauth_token'=>urlencode($this->session->userdata('oauth_token')),
                              'oauth_token_secret'=>urlencode($this->session->userdata('oauth_token_secret')));

    $this->load->library('dropbox', $params);

    $dbobj = $this->dropbox->account();

    print_r($dbobj);

}
```

Blockquote
i have used Dropbox library https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-Dropbox-API-Library
When i call to function request_dropbox() it gives me error in api "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports\application\libraries\Dropbox.php on line 478"
please help me how to access dropbox files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at your errors more carefully, it turns out that curl is not enabled on your Xampp environment.

This should help you out to enable CURL and get you going again.

[How to enable curl in xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp)

Comment: have u worked on this api. I m stock in middle of retrieving files from dropbox account. If u have worked on it please help me.