# PHP CURL function is not defined and DLL are not working

Tags: php, curl, dll, xampp

Whenever I start my XAMPP errors are showing up "the procedure entry point libssh2_scp_recv2 could not be located in the dynamic link libraryD:\Workspace\php\ext\php_curl.dll"

And other listed solutions are not working. Due to this, curl_init() function is not working.

Comment: Pardon, its 7.2.5

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp

Comment: @man0v : I have checked this link, i tried all of the steps listed but no luck. Also, there is not any php.ini present in xampp\apache\bin\php.ini

any lead?

Comment: @CD001 : done..

Comment: Do a search and find php.ini. This is where you would have to enable curl. It might be that they changed the path in a newer version.

Comment: Do you have any reference? @man0v

Comment: no I do not have a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for days, it was due to the wrong configurations of the Apache install. I re-installed it and now its working fine.

Posting it for the further people if they encounter the same issue.