# Installing Curl on xampp windows 8 for PHP 7

Tags: php, windows, curl, xampp

I have reviewed every question on this and still no solution.

I can confirm that

1 - php.ini is correctly referencing php_curl.dll (and this is the ini file in use)

2 - xampp/php is in my path

3 - I have copied various dlls to windows/system32

Started and stopped server a million times - still get curl_init() is undefined.

According to php installation I need this:

"In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, or, as of OpenSSL 1.1 libcrypto-*.dll and libssl-*.dll, must be present in your PATH. Also libssh2.dll must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site. "

I have done all of the above and still does not work. I have also installed OpenSSL on my pc.

What am I missing???

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp ?

Comment: Thanks, tried all that with no success. Kept getting "ordinal 384 not located" when loading curl and openssl.

SOLUTION was to install latest wamp - I would have done the same in xampp but for some reason they no longer support MySQL.