# Laravel: ext-curl, ext-simplexml problems on windows 10

Tags: laravel, curl, simplexml

I have some problem with **ext-curl, ext-simplexml** on **Laravel ^7.4**
I build a parser and it's perfectly working on native **php7**.
But when I thy to parse by same code on Laravel it show error on these **ext-curl, ext-simplexml** packages.

Do some once know, should I install by using installer those packages on **php7** if I have working code on **php7** but not on Laravel?
If not. What u suggestion?

***P.S.***

I found some solution to this problem: **sudo apt-get install php-curl**, but it's for **os** and **linux**. How can I do same on windows?

Comment: Have you enabled both extensions for `php-cli` and `php-fpm`? Sounds like you did for the former but not the latter.

Comment: I see extensions curl and simplexml, which I need, in cmd. And just extension curl enabled on php.ini. Other extensions like: simplexml, php-cli, php-fpm I didn't see on php.ini. Perhaps I should install it?

Comment: Or maybe I must check in other place?

Comment: create a new php file, use ` <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`, then save it, then use your xampp server & load it, it will show all the extensions you have enabled in php.ini file, then uncomment (remove ; in front of extensions to enable them), see this answer for hints, [how to enable curl in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp)